# Facebook adds parameters before # in Angular

Tags: angularjs, facebook, sails.js

I'm trying to do Facebook login using a sails.js backend only for REST API, no file serving (which we do in nginx).

I provide this as callback url to facebook: http://localhost/#/auth/facebook, but facebook prepends the code as a parameter before the hashtag, so http://localhost/?code=CODE#/auth/facebook, which causes angular/u-router to be unable to read it in stateParams/routeParams/location.

Any clues how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to fill a bug for this in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs